# how to create booth wallpaper 118 in by 98 in and 300 dpi file in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, file-size

W-3m
W-2.5m
Resolution-300 dpi
how to create booth wallpaper in this size I have already try but show me screch disk are full and I have already change screch disk then my all disk are full.

please give me answare and solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Normally you dont need more than 150-200 dpi on walls like this since the human visual aquity is based on distance*. Especially if text is vector anyway. People dont normally stand right next to booth walls the same way they would read a magazine. But if your getting paid then i think claiming disk is full is a bit ridiculous just buy more disk and/or move some stuff out.

* Most large scale poster adds, like the ones you see at a bus stop for example are only at 150 DPI for image elements. Or pure vector graphics.